# Code is not working in Android/Oxygen OS related phones but working in Galaxy phone

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-inflate

I deployed my app in playstore and its working in Galaxy phone without an issue but its crashing in Oxygen OS. Below is my code and error. Any suggestion is higly appreciated.

**Language Used**
Kotlin

**Options Tried**

myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

**Code:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    Picasso.get().load(testList[p1].Image).into(p0.imageView)
    p0.textView.text=testList[p1].Name
    p0.setClick(object:IRecyclerClick
    {
        override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {
         context.startActivity(Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java))
            Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            Common.selected_test=testList[position]

        }
    }
    )
}
```

**Error:**

```
2019-03-19 23:57:00.545 26980-26980/com.candy.testreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.candy.testreader, PID: 26980
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:912)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:888)
    at com.candy.testreader.Adapter.MyTestAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(MyTestAdapter.kt:39)
    at com.candy.testreader.Adapter.MyTestAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(MyTestAdapter.kt:50)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: What's context-  an activity context, or the application context?  If the latter, change to using an Activity context.  Which if you're in View code should be available.

Comment: activity cotext.

Comment: I am not sure why its working in galaxy phone but not in google os related phone. I am getting this error in my adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context object seems to be the issue, which context are you passing? On a safer side do something like this by getting the context from the initialised view
like

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
Picasso.get().load(testList[p1].Image).into(p0.imageView)
p0.textView.text=testList[p1].Name
p0.setClick(object:IRecyclerClick
{
    override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {
     view.context.startActivity(Intent(view.context,MainActivity::class.java))
        Intent(view.context, MainActivity::class.java)
        Common.selected_test=testList[position]

    }
}
)}
```

Edit: An explanation of why use the context as I explained is because a view which is inflated and visible to the user holds a reference to the context of the Activity it is in.

Read: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Thanks @king_below_my_lord for your comment. I am able to run my app in Google devices. Thanks for your help.